# How do I change the default application icon in Java?

Tags: java, icons

I'm using NetBeans, trying to change the familiar Java coffee cup icon to a png file that I have saved in a resources directory in the jar file.  I've found many different web pages that claim they have a solution, but so far none of them work.

Here's what I have at the moment (leaving out the try-catch block):

```
URL url = new URL("com/xyz/resources/camera.png");
Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Image img = kit.createImage(url);
getFrame().setIconImage(img);
```

The class that contains this code is in the **com.xyz** package, if that makes any difference.  That class also extends JFrame.  This code is throwing a MalformedUrlException on the first line.

Anyone have a solution that works?

Comment: See also: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setIconImages(java.util.List)
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon(java.net.URL)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
java.net.URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("com/xyz/resources/camera.png");
```

May or may not require a '/' at the front of the path.

Comment: Thanks.  This is a perfect example of why we need StackOverflow.  I found 100 different "solutions" by googling before I posted this question and got an answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: It's pretty safe to put the "/" in front.  Also, it lets you take the same string and do a getResourceAsStream, which is sometimes more useful.

Comment: Wow--the power of StackOverflow! :-)

Comment: Glad to help - I'd just not one day beforehand had to do something similar :)

Comment: And where is the png file actually stored?

Comment: JAR/classes/com/xyz/resources/camera.png
But you should be using Maven to manage your project and build, so in code it would be PROJECT/src/main/resources, and Maven will copy it into the correct place in its Jar/War creation phase.

Answer (score 14):

You can simply go Netbeans, in the design view, go to `JFrame` property, choose icon image property, Choose Set Form's `iconImage` property using: "Custom code" and then in the `Form.SetIconImage()` function put the following code:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(name_of_your_JFrame.class.getResource("image.png"))
```

Do not forget to import:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
```

in the source code!

Comment: what should be the size of image, whatever i import looks too small, or scalled??

Answer (score 4):

Or place the image in a location relative to a class and you don't need all that package/path info in the string itself.

```
com.xyz.SomeClassInThisPackage.class.getResource( "resources/camera.png" );
```

That way if you move the class to a different package, you dont have to find all the strings, you just move the class and its resources directory.

Comment: If you use a relative path and then create a subclass in a different package, that path will no longer be valid and your code will break. Using absolute paths prevents this (e.g. "/com/xyz/resources/camera.png")

Answer (score 4):

Try This write after

```
initcomponents();

setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("Your image address")));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    /** Creates new form Java Program1*/
    public Java Program1() 


    Image im = null;
    try {
    im = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/image location"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(chat.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    setIconImage(im);
```

This is what I used in the GUI in netbeans and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

You should define icons of various size, Windows and Linux distros like Ubuntu use different icons in Taskbar and Alt-Tab.

```
public static final URL ICON16 = HelperUi.class.getResource("/com/jsql/view/swing/resources/images/software/bug16.png");
public static final URL ICON32 = HelperUi.class.getResource("/com/jsql/view/swing/resources/images/software/bug32.png");
public static final URL ICON96 = HelperUi.class.getResource("/com/jsql/view/swing/resources/images/software/bug96.png");

List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    images.add(ImageIO.read(HelperUi.ICON96));
    images.add(ImageIO.read(HelperUi.ICON32));
    images.add(ImageIO.read(HelperUi.ICON16));
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error(e, e);
}

// Define a small and large app icon
this.setIconImages(images);
```

Answer (score 1):

In a class that extends a `javax.swing.JFrame` use method `setIconImage`.

```
this.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resource/icon.png")).getImage());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try **this one**, it works just fine :

```
`   ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(".//Ressources//User_50.png");
    this.setIconImage(icon.getImage());`
```

Answer (score -1):

inside frame constructor

```
try{    
       setIconImage(ImageIO.read(new File("./images/icon.png")));   
   }
catch (Exception ex){
       //do something
   }
```

Answer (score -2):

Example:

```
URL imageURL = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Gui/icon/report-go-icon.png");
ImageIcon iChing = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\RrezartP\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Inventari\\src\\Gui\\icon\\report-go-icon.png");      
btnReport.setIcon(iChing); 
System.out.println(imageURL);
```