# Changing the Desktop icon image example code not working

Tags: java, icons

[How do I change the default application icon in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209812/how-do-i-change-the-default-application-icon-in-java)

I tried the above code using Netbeans 7.0 but I'm not sure where the resources directory needs to be? If I use the one Netbeans has under files listing. It keeps giving me this error. Also, is the code correct?

```
Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(URLImageSource.java:115)
at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(URLImageSource.java:125)
at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:263)
at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:205)
at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:169)
```

using this code:

```
URL url;
url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/com/pbuddie/resources/Server.png");
Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Image img = kit.createImage(url);
clientUI.setIconImage(img);
```

Comment: have you tried using the path `com/pbuddie/resources/Server.png` i.e. no leading `/`

Comment: Yeah, looks like you got a bad file path... double checking it might be in order.

Comment: I'm using the folder which is created by netbeans "resources" which is on the same lvl a dist folder. I'm not sure If i need to create a folder resources somewhere, if so where do i add it? I took the leading / off still didn't work.. Do the contents of that resource get moved into the jar.. or do I have to do something to make that happen..