# How do I add an icon to my game

Tags: java, icons, slick, slick2d

I have made a simple game using Java with the library slick. I noticed all the other games have little icons on them, for example Mine craft has the little dirt block. can anyone tell me how i can have one of those? thank you.

Comment: Try Google or so and youll find. Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209812/how-do-i-change-the-default-application-icon-in-java

Comment: Before asking any question,firstly search on Google.

Answer (score 0):

From [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209812/how-do-i-change-the-default-application-icon-in-java).

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("path/to/icon.png");
Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Image img = kit.createImage(url);
getFrame().setIconImage(img);
```