# How to remove Java(TM) Se Binary from Task Manager and Show Swing Application Icon

Tags: java, swing, windows-10, taskmanager

[My Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBVM6.png)[image: Please Check Image]

Please have a look at Image, I have to remove Java(TM) Se binary and show only Icon of My Desktop Application in task manager.
Application icon I've already changed but in task manager it is showing Like Image.

Comment: You need to change java application's default icon. See [this answer to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209812/how-do-i-change-the-default-application-icon-in-java).

Comment: I am already done with this thing.            
 JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");

                frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/test/home_on.png")));

Comment: @cse what I am asking is bit diff. than what you have suggested....what you suggested I already done. I actually want to remove the Java (TM) Binary trademark....hope this would make my question lil clear.

Answer (score 0):

To perform that, you can use launch4j to create a seperate launcher with custom process name.

Comment: I have used launch4j but still it was same.