# App icon wrapped with launch4j not changing in taskar

Tags: launch4j

I wrapped my app.jar into app.exe using launch4j , the icon appearing on desktop is correct

[image]

but in the windows taskbar I still have the java icon

[image]

any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Launch4J's only job is to wrap your .jar into .exe, thus it can only set the icon for the exe.

If you want to have a custom icon in the taskbar and in your window, you must set a custom icon in your Java code. The solution for that depends on whether you use SWT, Swing, etc. But is should come down to getting the icon from the resources and setting it in your Window/Frame/...

For example: [How do I change the default application icon in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209812/how-do-i-change-the-default-application-icon-in-java)