# I need to change the image of my Java application

Tags: java, image

When I run my Java Application, the window has this icon of a white background with some guy with a red eye and a black and white body. Can I change that image in something else?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/209812/438992

Comment: The red dot on the mascot is not an eye. It is supposed to be a nose. But yeah, that "mascot" was probably drawn by an engineer, not by an artist.

Comment: Duke slander?! It was created by a graphic artist, btw, who also worked on Shrek etc.

Comment: We love [**Duke**](https://www.oracle.com/java/duke/).